Why the background of Box is still transparent when `background` is set?
I'm trying to write a group section widget, it wraps its content with a thin border and shows a title, looks like:

But it actually looks like:

I expect the yellow part to be opaque, so it would cover the line, but it looks transparent, why?
My code:
@Composable
fun Section(title: String, content: @Composable ()->Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = M
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(2.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .offset(10.dp, (-18).dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            Text( text = title, fontSize = 12.sp, modifier = M.padding(10.dp, 0.dp))
        }
        content()
    }
}

// and usage:
Section(title = "Section Title") {
    Column {
        Text("row 1")
        Text("row 2")
        Text("row 3")
    }
}


You need to take-out text with the background out of parent Box because, children inside Box will always be drawn inside it, not over it.
Sample changes:
@Composable
fun Section(title: String, content: @Composable ()->Unit) {
    Box {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(2.dp)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            content()
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .offset(10.dp, (0).dp)
                .zIndex(1f)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            Text( text = title, fontSize = 12.sp, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp, 0.dp))
        }
    }
}

